# How do I compare elements in a vector(class)?

Tags: java, android, vector

I'm making a game and when i update the coordinates of the "entities", if they exceed the screen limit, they will appear in another part, and score will get increased, but how could be more than one entity, the score will get increased more than once, so I've tried using this in the for each cycle:

```
for(entity e: entities){
//updating stuff
    if(e.exceed_the_limit)//or whatever
    { 
        if(e.equals(entities.get(entities.size)))score++;
    }
}
```

So it should compare if the element is the first of the vector to increase score, but i get this exception:

*java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1t*

I've tried with *elementAt()* but i get the same error. What should I do to check if it's the first time it increases?

Comment: `entities.get(entities.size) should entities.get(entities.size - 1)`

Comment: What you are trying to do here doesn't make sense. This code (if you take @chengpohi's fix) will check if every entity is the last one in the list, and if so, increment the score. But there will always be one entity that is the last one in the list, so you are essentially just incrementing the score every update.

Comment: @Vincent I know that, i though it wasn't necesary to put it there in the example code.